# How can a widget be created in Android Studio?

Tags: android, widget, android-studio

I recently started using Android Studio instead of Eclipse. Previously I made a widget in Eclipse and when switching to Android Studio, I could easily open it there.

However, I can't quite figure out how to create a blank widget in Android Studio. When creating a new project in Android Studio I can choose between a Blank Activity, a Fullscreen Activity or a Master/Detail Flow. Since I'm making just a widget and not an activity the first two aren't the right ones and the third one doesn't seem to be what I want either.

Comment: http://techglimpse.com/how-to-interactive-app-tap-event-listener/ you can take some help from this link.

Comment: If you mean a "homescreen widget" here's an example for Android Studio: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new project, just uncheck the "Create activity box"

[image: disable activity creation]

Comment: Ah, that really helpst, thanks :) I'm guessing that all I need to do after that is add the appropriate receivers?

Comment: That's  correct,  as you would do it in Eclipse,  any tutorial you find will work just fine with Android Studio. Feel free to accept the answer if answered to your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Hi I can see this might be an old question but. Hope this helps newbies...

I am using Android Studio 1.0.2 and has some awesome features to generate most of the stuff that if you follow many tutorials out there. Is just a click away. On android studio i'm using just right click, select new and Widget App > then every file needed is generated for you based on the size of widget you want.

Happy coding .... !